# не удается прошить esp32. the port doesn't exist

Tags: linux, ubuntu, esp32

Я уже в течении долгого времени пытаюсь прошить esp-wroom-32, но у меня ничего не получается. idf.py выдает такую ошибку:

```
Serial port /dev/ttyUSB0
A fatal error occurred: Could not open /dev/ttyUSB0, the port doesn't exist
CMake Error at run_serial_tool.cmake:55 (message):
  /home/matvey/.espressif/python_env/idf5.1_py3.9_env/bin/python;;/home/matvey/esp/esp-idf/components/esptool_py/esptool/esptool.py;--chip;esp32
  failed
FAILED: CMakeFiles/flash /home/matvey/esp/esp-idf/examples/get-started/hello_world/build/CMakeFiles/flash 
cd /home/matvey/esp/esp-idf/components/esptool_py && /usr/bin/cmake -D IDF_PATH=/home/matvey/esp/esp-idf -D "SERIAL_TOOL=/home/matvey/.espressif/python_env/idf5.1_py3.9_env/bin/python;;/home/matvey/esp/esp-idf/components/esptool_py/esptool/esptool.py;--chip;esp32" -D "SERIAL_TOOL_ARGS=--before=default_reset;--after=hard_reset;write_flash;@flash_args" -D WORKING_DIRECTORY=/home/matvey/esp/esp-idf/examples/get-started/hello_world/build -P /home/matvey/esp/esp-idf/components/esptool_py/run_serial_tool.cmake
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
ninja failed with exit code 1, output of the command is in the /home/matvey/esp/esp-idf/examples/get-started/hello_world/build/log/idf_py_stderr_output_27303 and /home/matvey/esp/esp-idf/examples/get-started/hello_world/build/log/idf_py_stdout_output_27303
```

Я понятия не имею в чем может быть проблема, я менял настройки udev, но может это сделать у меня не получилось.

Comment: Покажи dmesg при подключении платы

Comment: А ты permissions на `/dev/ttyUSB0` поставил? По умолчанию там вроде только у рута и у пользователь USB доступы есть, тебе надо юзера с которого прошиваешь добавить в пользователей usb